# How to make small content fill UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have created a UIWebView, banner sized, which is a subview of my UITabBar. I have placed it right on top of the tab bar. I know I have done this correctly since loading for example google.com gives me the exact appearance I am after.

For my banner though, I want to load a picture from my Google Drive account. This appears to be to small because it does not fill the web view when I am running on iPad and I therefore end up with an annoying space between the banner and the tab bar, respectively between the banner and the right screen edge.

Is there any way I can scale the content to exactly fit the web view?

EDIT: The code which I am using to show the image in the web view:

```
// Tab bar initialization
TabbeBarreViewController *tabViewController = [[TabbeBarreViewController alloc] init];
[tabViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers];


// Banner set up
CGSize tabBarSize = [[tabViewController tabBar] bounds].size;

UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - tabBarSize.height - tabBarSize.width/4.0, tabBarSize.width, tabBarSize.width/4.0)];

[wv setOpaque:NO];
[wv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[wv setHidden:YES];
[[wv scrollView] setScrollEnabled:NO];


[wv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/11MLox_3u0iqNwk3UdmCd4YHWYMSLxzbkyfgQjUJuSko/pub?w=606&h=152"]]];
[[tabViewController view] addSubview:wv];
[wv setDelegate:self];

// Presenting tab bar with subview banner
[self presentViewController:tabViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
{
    CGSize contentSize = theWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

    float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;

    theWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
    theWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
    theWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;

    theWebView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Why show the picture through a webview? Why not display it as a UIImageView and configure a tap gesture recognizer to handle taps on it?

Comment: can you show us the code you are using to show image in imageview?

Comment: I want to show it through the webview in order to be able to change the picture whenever I want. I do not know how to do this with a UIImage. If you know how to, please show me! :)

Comment: Edited above to present the code I am using

Answer (score 1):

You can try small piece of `HTML` code here to load content into the webview as below

```
NSString *HTML=@"<html><body padding=\"0\"><img src=\"imgurl\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/></body></html>";
[self.webview loadHTMLString:HTML baseURL:nil];
```

**Edit**

Or, you can add a `UIImageView` instead like below

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOURIMAGEURL"]]];
self.imagView.image=image;
```

Comment: This works fine for getting the image to fill the gap down to the tab bar. It does not show the complete image though, and thus gives me a thin gap to the screen edge on each side though. An idea how to fix this?

Comment: Then I would suggest you to simply use `UIImageView` if you need to show only image.

Comment: Can I load an URL into an UIImageView?

Comment: Ok, so I tried your code. Worked indeed, but it locked the complete application until the image was loaded and thus makes the app useless on a slow connection...

Comment: @OscarWyck Yes it will unlock because you are downloading it synchronously, try downloading the image asynchronously it will work fine..